# Javascript mousemove event not triggered when in object

Tags: javascript, events, scope, mousemove

I hope your doing fine.
Here's my problem :

This code works fine :

```
var imageMover = {
    mouseDown: function(e) {
        e.target.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved, false);
        console.log('mouseDown');
    },
    mouseUp: function(e) {
        e.target.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved, false);
        console.log('mouseUp');
    }
};
function mouseMoved(e) {
    console.log("mouseMoved");
}
```

While this one is not :

```
var imageMover = {
    mouseDown: function(e) {
        e.target.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoved, false);
        console.log('mouseDown');
    },
    mouseUp: function(e) {
        e.target.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoved, false);
        console.log('mouseUp');
    },
    mouseMoved: function(e) {
        console.log("mouseMoved");
    }
};
```

To give a little more context: There are thumbnails you can click on.
When you click on it, the image is added to a container, and the events mouseUp and mouseDown are added to the image.
When someone click on the image, i'd like the event mouseMouve to be attached so I can follow the image position.

mouseUp and mouseDown are well attached, and well triggered, but mouseMouve only works when it is not inside my imageMover object.
It seems to be a scope problem, but I can't figure why it acts like that.

In advance, many thanks !

Comment: how are you calling `imageMover`.Better  if you can share the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The this from this.mouseMoved is refering to the event target, which is the DOM element not the object storing the methods.

```js
var imageMover = {
  mouseDown: function(e) {
    console.log( 'this is refering to => ', this );
    e.target.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoved, false);
  }
};

document.querySelector( '.container' ).addEventListener( 'mousedown', imageMover.mouseDown );
```

```css
.container
{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly ! Thanks a lot. So, I just have to replace this.mouseDown by imageMover.mouseDown and that's ok.